# PowerShell - Why is my button not clickable during a while loop?

Tags: function, powershell, loops, while-loop, click

This is my function:

```
Function StartProgress
{
    $x = 600
    $length = $x / 100
        while($x -gt 0) {
        $min = [int](([string]($x/60)).split('.')[0])
        $lblCnt.Text = " " + $min + " minutes " + ($x % 60) + " seconds left"
        $pbrCnt.Value = $pbrCnt.Maximum - $x
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        $x--
        }
}
```

and I have added it here:

```
$timer.add_Tick({StartProgress})
```

In the main form there's a button that isn't clickable during my while loop. Why?

Comment: my understanding is that the GUI is single threaded unless you code to add multi-threading. that means _everything_ waits for any loop.

Comment: I don't think so. If I remove the `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` then I can click on my button, but `$min` becomes wrong.

Comment: your function forces EVERYTHING to wait ... and when you remove the delay, you simply shorten the time that everything must wait.

Comment: What do you suggest that I do then to let the button work?

Comment: from what i understand of GUI code, you will need to put anything that blocks your GUI into a loop designed to make frequent updates of the GUI ... OR put the blocking code into a different thread ... OR switch to c#. take a look as runspaces or the PoshRSJob module for ways to use runspaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, forcing a **synchronous sleep with `Start-Sleep` blocks the UI thread as a whole and makes your form unresponsive**.

**Instead of using `Start-Sleep`, let the timer invoke your function periodically**, once every second; you then need to keep track of your state using a script-level variable:

```
$script:x = 600

Function StartProgress {
  $length = $script:x / 100
  $min = [int](([string]($script:x / 60)).split('.')[0])
  $lblCnt.Text = " " + $min + " minutes " + ($script:x % 60) + " seconds left"
  $pbrCnt.Value = $pbrCnt.Maximum - $script:x
  if (--$script:x -eq 0) { $timer.Dispose() }
}

$timer.Interval = 1000 # 1 sec.
$timer.add_Tick({StartProgress})
$timer.Start()
```

Note how `.Dispose()` is called on `$timer` when `$script:x` reaches `0`, to prevent further events from getting generated; if processing stops earlier, you must call `$timer.Dispose()` manually.

Answer (score 0):

in a while loop you will not come to a moment, where your application have time to trigger updates. Without throwing updates (PropertyChangedEvent, etc.), the UI will not be notified of changed data.

Comment: How could I change the code to let the button work?